# What is the weapon Adlet uses to spit fire called?

Tags: rokka-no-yuusha

In the first episode of Rokka no Yuusha, Adlet uses some kind of tool to spit out fire.

[image: Adlet and his tool]

What is this tool called? Is there a real life equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a real world equivalent to this device. The closest thing that I can compare it to is when someone has a torch and [they spit some alcohol through the flame](http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/arts/circus-arts/fire-breathing.htm).

Adlet most likely came up with this device through his extensive years of training with Atoro.

Comment: Could you maybe provide a link to the alcohol thing?

Comment: http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/arts/circus-arts/fire-breathing.htm

Comment: If it's ony used for a spark then it could possibly be that one piece could be flint and the other steel so that when he moves his teeth a certain way a spark is struck

Answer (score 0):

Its not as much as a weapon as much as it is just 2 pieces of Flint and Steel.
Adlet has something flammable in his mouth that is liquid (Such as gasoline or alcohol) and strikes the flint and steel while blowing outwards causing a sort of flame to come from his mouth. Its not very effective since the flame dies out quickly but if the enemy is covered in something flammable it can be extremely devastating

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully in the first fight between Adlet + Nachetanya against the fiends or more recently when Adlet escapes Mora after she frames him, this is actually a two stage weapon. First, Adlet throws those "water bombs" which are actually a flammable chemical. Then he grinds/clicks the flint and steel or other sparking device on his teeth together. At close range the sparks ignite the liquid previously placed, making it seem like he is breathing fire/explosions.